# Error "WebView.Context" when running WebView

Tags: swiftui, webview

I'm learning how to make a webview from youtube, however i followed every step of their code, however my code got an error while their code did not. I can't run but they can. Error said "Cannot convert value of type 'WebView.Context' (aka 'UIViewRepresentableContext') to expected argument type 'URLRequest'"

Can someone point out the problem? Thank you.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import UIKit
import SwiftUI


struct ContentViewww: View {
 var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink {
            WebView(url: URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com")!)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        } label: {
            Text("open website")
                .padding(10)
                .background(.black)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
   }
   }

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

 var url : URL
 func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
     let web = WKWebView()
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    web.load(context)
    return web
    
 }

 func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    let web = WKWebView()
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    web.load(request)
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to load `request` not `context`.

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
  let web = WKWebView()
  let request = URLRequest(url: url)
  web.load(request) //modified
  return web

}
```